# I have a Ford Expedition and my spark plug is broken

Tags: sparkplugs

Here is my broken spark plug.
The porcelain is not letting the 'easy out' do its job.
How can I take it out?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm wondering why you're trying to use an easy out when it appears the hex portion of the spark plug is still intact? What is stopping you from putting a socket on what is left and pulling it out?

Comment: Its stripped its completely round that's why I can't take it out

Comment: Use a six sided socket. Since the porcelain is gone, you don't need a deepwell. Leaves a lot more options for you.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 - Aren't spark plug sockets (the task specific deep ones with the cushion inside) typically 6 sided? The OP should be primarily concerned with using the **correct size** of 6 sided socket.

Comment: @Jeeped ... I think that is sort of implied?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 - You'd think so but the spark plug's hex got rounded off somehow. Given the torque applied to install a spark plug (typically 10-20 ft/lbs) it seems a bit incredulous to me that the hex was rounded off to the point where the correct size of 6-sided spark plug socket wouldn't still remove it. If anything I would have thought the threads would strip first. There's even a heli-coil for that.

Answer (score 1):

Get a square-cut "easy out", soak the plug in penetrating oil and let sit for a few minutes. Drive the easy-out into the plug shell and remove. It should take anywhere from 7-15ft-lbs of torque to remove, but can be significantly higher if the plug is frozen. It also helps (if you can) to move the cylinders to bottom-dead travel and be careful not to drive the easy-out into the cylinder.

Comment: Don’t you mean “pistons” rather than “cylinders”

Answer (score 0):

If you use the socket style bolt removing easy out  set they sell at Napa. I think  that would be the best way. They sell for $35 for a set of 5. But then your not driving any tool into your heads and potentially making a already bad situation worse. Driving a easy out into a cylnder head is a bad idea and sounds a little impulsive. Take your time slow down an use the rite tool for the situation. Sounds like rushing things might be what got you in this position to begin with. But again I would do everything I could to avoid smashing any thing in the head of my truck. I'm sure it could work and you might pull it out without any noticable damage to your truck but i Can not see in any way this working and not dropping some kind of crap into the cylnder and that causes damage to rings, valves , heads, pistons and what not. Any way you probibly allready found a solution I was just hoping to save someone from taking the driving a easy out advise and potentially running there head and there day